# Can CloudKit subscriptions not be created in code?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I've got 'dynamic' subscriptions that I need to create when the app runs and these cannot be pre-determined as they're based on some unique ID I generate temporarily for each device connecting. When running in development mode, CloudKit works perfectly however in Distribution mode I keep getting this error:

```
<CKError 0x1358436e0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "attempting to create a subscription in a production container"; uuid = 41F4CA23-9849-40B1-8DB5-0030BBD91251; container ID = "iCloud.com.company.CloudKit">
```

Is there no way to create a subscription dynamically? I thought only RecordTypes needed to be created using the Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be something else. I was previously using the `saveSubscription` method of the private database. This apparently kept giving me the above mentioned error. I ended up using `CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation` and `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` and this now works perfectly.

In my case I did have the subscription types setup in Production and also had everything else setup correctly. It was just the matter of using the above mentioned operations instead and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely create subscriptions dynamically in the production environment of your CloudKit container. If you're using a query subscription for a specific record type, you'll need to make sure that the record type exists in production (in other words, that you've migrated your schema to production).

Keep in mind that the production environment is used in beta testing as well.

Comment: So what does Apple mean when they say `Subscriptions must be created in the Development environment first and then promoted to Production. Attempting to create a subscription directly in the Production environment will result in an error.` on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cksubscription? I'm hopefully I can still use `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` against a production environment since my subscriptions are changeable by the user.

Comment: There are subscriptions and "subscription types".  What Apple meant to write in
          https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cksubscription?language=objc​
is:
   "Subscription types must be created in the Development environment first and then promoted to Production. Attempting to create a subscription type directly in the Production environment will result in an error."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is impossible to use TRUEPREDICATE for subscription in production container, it is true for both of methods (saveSubscription and CKModifySubscriptionsOperation).
Just change predicate for get successful subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation by Apple on this is confusing, but every `CKQuerySubscription` with a unique combination of a `Record Type` and other undocumented elements like `NSPredicate`, results in a new ***subscription type*** that must first exist in **Development** environment, and from there deployed in **Production** environment, before you can make a new subscription for a user using the same combination of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I rediscovered my answer above and benefited from rereading it.  So may I clarify...

1. a 'particular' CKSubscription must first be entered in the development environment and then deployed to the Production environment.
2. A 'particular' CKSubscription must have some things the same (not sure exactly what things) but it can have some things different and still reference the same CKSubscription deployed to Production.  For example:

   a)     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type" = %@",@"BBH"];     notification.alertBody=@"Event: %1$@";
   or
   b)     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type" = %@",@"NSBH"];
   notification.alertBody=@"Date: %1$@";

can both be in the same 'particular' CKSubscription deployed to Production.  That means each user can personalize their subscription using the %@ entry in a query predicate and differing CKNotificationInfo.

3. A 'particular CKSubscription cannot have different 'bodies' in its predicate.  That means that the predicate:

   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type" = %@",@"BBH"];

cannot be used in a CKSubscription that was deployed with:

```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Event" = %@",@"BBH"];
```

4. A single CKSubscription applies to all devices logged into the same Apple ID.  That means an updated app running on device 1 will send updated subscriptions to a different device running an older version of that app.